# Create a fallback URL if app is not installed using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, deep-linking

I'm attempting to make a plugin that converts normal links into deep links when a user is browsing on an Android or iOS device. So, for example, it finds the link and replaces it with the deep link like this:

```
var facebookURL  = $('[href*="facebook.com"]');
var facebookDeep = 'fb://profile/123456789';
$(facebookURL).attr('href', facebookDeep);
```

When the link is clicked and Facebook is installed, the link will open up the Facebook app. If Facebook isn't installed, however, when the link is clicked, nothing happens. So I figured that I would just automatically open the web URL if there was still a focus on the frame after 1000ms:

```
$($(facebookURL)).click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
      location.href = 'https://facebook.com';
    } else {
      console.log('Focus was lost');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

But this logs *Focus was lost*.

Any ideas on another way I can accomplish this? Or if there's an easier way to create a fallback.

Comment: `$(this).blur()` "blurs" the specified element, it doesn't check if it doesn't have focus ... the return value will always be "truthy" ... see [this](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) for an explanation of what you arre doing

Comment: Okay, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
```

to this:

```
if ($(facebookURL).is(":focus")) {
```

More info: [The 'this' problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#The_this_problem)